# How to create simple table in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, ms-access-2007, resultset

I am working on a project "Hospital Management System" in Java Swing. Now on the records page I want to show all stored records of patients in a table format. But I have never worked with JTable in swing. Now when I tried to fetch records in a simple program, it is printing all records on console in for loop but when I go for JFrame and tried to fetch records on JTable, instead of making a table, it's showing a error message like:

```
Ex_test.java:51: cannot find symbol, symbol  : constructor JTable(java.lang.String[],java.lang.String[][])
location: class javax.swing.JTable, JTable table=new JTable(column,data);
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code?

Database is MS-Access 2007.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Ex_test extends JFrame
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Ex_test ob=new Ex_test();
    }
    int i=0;
    String column[];
    String data[][];
    //JTable table; 
    public Ex_test()
    {
        super("Array");
        String[] id=new String[15];
        String[] name=new String[15];
        String[] contact=new String[15];

        try
        {
            Connection con;
            Statement st;
            ResultSet rs;

            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:test");
            st=con.createStatement();
            rs=st.executeQuery("select * from test");
            String column[]={"ID","NAME","CONTACT"};
            while (rs.next())
            {
                    id[i]=rs.getString("id");
                    name[i]=rs.getString("sname");
                    contact[i]=rs.getString("contact");
                    i++;
            }   
            for (i=0;i<4 ;i++ )
            {
                System.out.println(""+id[i]+name[i]+contact[i]);
                String data[][]={{id[i],name[i],contact[i] }};              
            }           
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }   
        JTable table=new JTable(column,data);
        setSize(1000,1000);
        setVisible(true);       
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JTable table=new JTable(column,data); // wrong parameters
```

The constructor expects you to specify the data as the first parameter:

```
JTable table=new JTable(data, column);
```

Don't use Arrays for reading data from a database. You don't know how large to make the arrays. Instead use Vectors, since the DefaultTableModel will support Vectors.

Check out the `TableFromDatabaseExample.java` source code from [Table From Database](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) for some general code to get you started in populating a JTable with data from a database.

Also, don't use an empty catch block on the SQL code. You should display the exception.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, I see you haven't read my blog. The first suggestion it makes is to search the web for  `ResultSetTableModel` :)

Comment: Oops, my bad.  :P  Noise deleted.